# vaadin uix response slow after idle time

Tags: java, vaadin14

perhaps a very simple question, but I did not find any  answer so far. We are using vaadin14, but I guess, that it is independent of the version.
When opening vaadin in the browser and let the browser open for a longer time (half an hour/one hour or more) without interaction, then it lasts very long when trying to open a popup or reading data into a grid for the first time. Repeated reads or actions then work as fast as expected afterwards. After a periode of time, the behaviour is the same again.
It seems, that the frontend and backend looses there connection or something like that and have to synchronize with each other after a long idle time.

Perhaps there are some settings to let the ui and the backend talk to each other in the background to avoid this situation. Thanks in advance for every idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the server may be restarting from time to time. Where is your application deployed?

Comment: Hi, the server is on the same machine and not restarting. Otherwise the session would have been lost and could not reconnect without new login into the application.

Comment: Thanks. Have you checked for a memory leak?